# [keyboard] vs. [keyboard-controls]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was hopping from one question to another today and came across [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-to-remove-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses) ... it's a perfectly good question about keyboard limitations, but it's tagged [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) and [keyboard-controls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-controls).

I'm not entirely sure that there's a difference between the two tags in the context of gaming. Interestingly, there's currently little overlap between the tags (only 3 questions use them both; there are 20 and 27 questions in those tags), but the overall theme seems to be the same.

Do we need both tags? If not, can we decide which tag should rule and which should serve, and then set it up accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's possible to make a distinction between the tags - for instance, using [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) to ask about physical keyboards and [keyboard-controls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-controls) to ask about key-binding in games.

However, I don't think we should do it, it's too confusing. If a new user wants to ask something about keyboard controls in a game and then sees both "keyboard" and "keyboard-controls" in the auto-complete, what would that user choose? Problematic.

I vote for making [keyboard-controls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-controls) a synonym of [keyboard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard).

Comment: Ze checkmark goes here!